# Stop the kafka connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

In kafka connect `SinkTask` implementation, If there is an exception which is unavoidable, if I invoke `stop()` method from my code, does the connector stop altogether ?

Answer (score 1):

Only that task that encountered the exception will stop

The connect cluster can have multiple connectors which won't stop, and there can be other tasks for a single connect depending on your configurations that, for example, would be assigned different, clean, data that could be processed