# Kafka connect : Stop the task, are offsets committed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have code as below in kafka connect SinkTask implementation. For critical exceptions I want to invoke `stop()` in a task and stop the task.

I needed to know if I goto `stop()` does kafka connect commit the offsets in kafka topic's partitions ? i.e. if I handle my exception, log it, perform some activities based on the exception and invoke `stop()`, are the topic's offsets (application topics) committed because there is no exception from `put()`? I am assuming because there is no successful run from `put()` or it was not completed for a batch (based on max poll records) offsets should not be completed, so that when I retry, no records will be missed. Please let me know if any one can provide suggestion if offsets are not committed?

Code :

```
public class ExampleSinkTask extends SinkTask {
    @Override
    public void start(Map<String, String> map) {
    ....

    }

    @Override
    private void doSomeCriticalOperation()  {
        // call stop if critical operation fails. 

        ...

        // Exception handled, close the task (allow user interference in such cases) 
        stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void put(Collection<SinkRecord> collection)  {
        ..
        doSomeCriticalOperation();
        ..

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        log.info("*** Stopping Kafka task completely ***");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop the kafka connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943994/stop-the-kafka-connector)

Comment: This question is about offset commits in case of calling `stop()`